# How to build the below tree with EXTJS?

Tags: extjs

Below mentioned is a required tree.I want to use the same with the 'img'[directory] & symbols( '+', '-') for expansion & compression.I'm not much familiar with EXTJS.right now i'm running EXTJS through html & js.can any1 help me to do with the exact code ?

```
-[img] PARENT
    -[img] FIRST LEVEL CHILD 1
        -[img] SECOND LEVEL CHILD
                [img] THIRD LEVEL CHILD 1
                [img] THIRD LEVEL CHILD 2
                [IMG] THIRD LEVEL CHILD 3
     +[img] FIRST LEVEL CHILD 2
     +[img] FIRST LEVEL CHILD 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the samples in the [Sencha Website](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/)? There's  a good example of how to asynchronously load data.  Use firebug to see the JSON that comes back from the PHP.  It will give you a good idea of how to structure your JSON from the back end.

The example will also show you how to structure your EXT code as well.

In the JSON, you'll see a property called 'cls' . This is the CSS class ID that will be used in your Tree Node. Leave these alone until you are able to get the tree itself running.

Once you get some source code going, edit your question so that we can help you some more.